# Cannot change timezone info on linux system

Tags: linux, timezone

Anyone know why 'Not a directory' is being output preventing me from changing timezone?

```
[root@server etc]# cat localtime 
cat: localtime: Not a directory
[root@server etc]# ls localtime 
ls: localtime: Not a directory
[root@server etc]# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Eire localtime 
ln: accessing `localtime': Not a directory
[root@server etc]# ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Nome localtime 
ln: accessing `localtime': Not a directory
[root@server etc]# date
Thu Apr 24 09:58:44 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Not a directory error' is coming because here localtime is a symbolic link not a directory.

using command:ls -l localtime
gives: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 27 Oct 31 19:00 localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC

as output.
Here 'l' in the begining means that localtime is a symbolic link.

For the command : ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Eire localtime
to work,

delete the existing symbolic link localtime as : rm localtime

then use command :
better see [This link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/change-timezone-in-linux/)

Comment: :I'm able to execute same command in my machine without deleting localtime file

Comment: @Rahul Please explain the things if u know as I am a fresher ,It will help me to understand  well.

Comment: There is no /etc/localtime in bobbyrne01's system at all

Comment: but in my system localtime is there still ,It gives the same ouptput

Comment: after deleting the symbolic link I could change timezone